# Can a WebForms application in Asp.net 4.5.1 developed in Visual Studio 2013 be opened and worked on in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2019, asp.net-4.5

I have an Asp.net 4.5.1 Web Forms project developed on Visual Studio 2013. I want to start using Visual Studio 2019. When I open the project in Visual Studio 2019 I get errors in many places.

For example:

> IDE0005 Using directive is unnecessary

> CS0234 The type or namespace name 'AspNet' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

> CS0246 The type or namespace name 'OwinStartup' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

and other or similar errors.

Is it possible to continue developing this project as is in Visual Studio 2019 without making fundamental changes?

Will I have similar or other problems using Visual Studio 2015 to continue developing this project?

Thank you!

Comment: First, you need to update asp.net version to the latest version. Second, please reinstall the related reference in the nuget-package. If you want to solve the specific problem, please provide the related code or upload your project here.

Comment: @Jack What to update to the latest version, the version of the project? What is the related reference to reinstall in the nuget-package?

Comment: You can right-click properties to change target framework to .net framework4.8. As for the related reference, it depends on the specific code. Since I don't have it, I can not make a test.

Comment: @Jack Will that enable using Visual Studio 2019 for the project? What about Visual Studio 2015, does anything specific have to be done to use it for my project?

Comment: There is no need for you to set something for vs2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to update asp.net version(.net Framework version) to the latest version.
(Please right-click properties->Target framework->.net framework 4.8)

Second, please reinstall the related reference in the nuget-package.

I will make an example for your question about OwinStartup problem:

Please see the following picture to add the nuget-package in vs2019.

[image]

If the IntelliSense isn't appear, please search it in the nuget-package.(Right click-References->Manage Nuget Packages)